# Is there a way to Fix the CSV File data with comma spilled

Tags: python, csv

There is this possibility of data expected for Data Loading, that has to be sanitized. 
Is there a dynamic way of achieving this?by marking the columns or some other way
The current data is in this format

```
ID,Name,Description,Qty,Cost,days,Reason
1,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
2,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
3,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
4,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
5,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
6,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
7,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
8,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
9,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
10,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
```

Expected Result

```
   ID,Name,Description,Qty,Cost,days,Reason
1,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
2,Faleis,'Mangoe',10,90,60,good
3,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
4,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
5,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
6,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
7,Faleis,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,good
8,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
9,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
10,ApleQT,'Apple,VitaminE,D',10,90,60,'Not good, punctured'
```

Please kindly show me , how i can achieve this . @Mark Tolonen and @satilog Please help

Comment: You'll have to read it line by line and find some logic to tell wether a `,` is part of the field or a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a quick "dirty" regex would help to fix the broken CSV:

```
txt = '''ID,Name,Description,Qty,Cost,days,Reason
1,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
2,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
3,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
4,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
5,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
6,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
7,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
8,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured
9,Faleis,Mangoe,10,90,60,good
10,ApleQT,Apple,VitaminE,D,10,90,60,Not good, punctured'''

import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = re.sub(r'(.*?,.*?,)([^\d]+)(,[\d,]+,)(.*)', r'\1"\2"\3"\4"', txt)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID    Name       Description  Qty  Cost  days               Reason
0   1  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
1   2  Faleis            Mangoe   10    90    60                 good
2   3  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
3   4  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
4   5  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
5   6  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
6   7  Faleis            Mangoe   10    90    60                 good
7   8  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
8   9  Faleis            Mangoe   10    90    60                 good
9  10  ApleQT  Apple,VitaminE,D   10    90    60  Not good, punctured
```

Comment: But i need in comma delimited only not space please. but thanks

Comment: @Gabriel That's only how `pandas` prints the dataframe to screen. To save correct csv do `df.to_csv('data.csv')` and your file will be correctly delimited.